# Max232 to DB9 connection confusion

Tags: 8051, max232

[image]

The picture shows standard connection between 8051 and DB-9 via MAX232. 14th pin is the translated output of the transmitted data by 8051, so this should be connected to the receiver pin of DB-9, which is pin 3, but here it goes to pin 2, which is called 'transmitted data', so should we read "transmitted data=receiver of DB-9" and "Received data=transmitter of DB-9"? Because, to me the DB-9
Label seems opposite as expected.

Comment: It depends on if you want your DB9 to be wired as DTE or DCE. Connecting 2 DTE's together requires a cable that cross connects TX and RX.

Comment: How the transmitter pin is tied to 14? Transmitter pin shoud be expected to transmit something to 8051, not to take the transmitted data by pin 14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's 2 common pinouts for DB9 RS232, `Data Terminal equipment` (DTE) and `Data Circuit-terminating Equipment` (DCE).

DTE is the male DB9 pinout typically found on PC's.
DCE is the female DB9 pinout found on various RS232 devices such as modems.

The pinouts for DTE and DCE are such that the transmit pin on the one type matches the receive pin on the other type and vice versa...
Connecting 2 DTE devices together (such as 2 PC's) requires what is known as a "null-modem" cable that crosses RXD and TXD.

[image]
[Image Source](https://subheavy.weebly.com/blog/epson-serial-cable-pinout-db9-to-db9)

As you can see, your schematic above matches the pinout for the DB9 Female DCE. This allows the device to be connected to a PC (DTE) with a normal 1 to 1 male-female DB9 cable.